# Vue App doesn't refresh when pressing enter in firefox address bar

Tags: vue.js, firefox, refresh, vue-router

When clicking into the firefox address bar and **pressing enter the Vue App doesn't refresh**.

The same behavior is triggering a reload on Chrome.
F5 and Strg+R refreshs as expected on Firefox.

Firefox version: 67.0.1 (64 bit)

The Vue.js App uses Vue Router.
My url structure is: https://www.url.com/#/sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem with your application but with the FF, Try to refresh with Ctrl + F5, [How do I set FF so hitting enter in the address bar refreshes a page if it's already loaded?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1208635)

Comment: However refresh by enter in the address bar works fine for other web pages.Maybe it is because of the vue routing (hash in the url). My url structure is: https://www.test.com/#/site

Comment: Setting the history mode resolved the issue:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: This is because Vue Router does not notice any change if the same component is being addressed. But when history mode is selected it will use history.pushState API, calling pushState() is similar to setting window.location = "#foo", in that both will also create and activate another history entry associated with the current document.